# Enqueue/Dequeue two linked lists simultaneously in C

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I have two linked lists that I track using inputFront, inputRear, outputFront & outputRear. My problem arises when I enqueue the data from input into output. Printf prints only the first item from the input. Ex: my input is "a b c", it will only return "a". I'd appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
struct linked_list{
    char *operand;
    struct linked_list *next;
};    

void enqueue(struct linked_list** queueFront, struct linked_list** queueRear,
    char* token);
char* dequeue(struct linked_list** queueFront, struct linked_list** queueRear);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct linked_list *inputFront = NULL, *inputRear = NULL;
    struct linked_list *outputFront = NULL, *outputRear = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        enqueue(&inputFront, &inputRear, argv[i]);

    for (struct linked_list *p = inputFront; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        enqueue(&outputFront, &outputRear, dequeue(&inputFront, &inputRear));


    for (struct linked_list *p = outputFront; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("%s \n", dequeue(&outputFront, &outputRear));
}

void enqueue(struct linked_list** queueFront, struct linked_list** queueRear,
    char* token){
    struct linked_list* newNode = (struct linked_list*) malloc(
        sizeof(struct linked_list));
    newNode->operand = token;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (*queueRear == NULL && *queueFront == NULL){
        *queueFront = *queueRear = newNode;
        return;
    }

    (*queueRear)->next = newNode;
    *queueRear = newNode;
}

char* dequeue(struct linked_list** queueFront, struct linked_list** queueRear){
    if (*queueFront != NULL){
        struct linked_list *remv = *queueFront;
        char *remOperand = (*queueFront)->operand;
        *queueFront = remv->next;
        if (remv == (*queueRear))
            *queueRear = NULL;
        free(remv);
        return remOperand;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] with an example of input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Well, you got help. It would be polite to give feedback whether it has helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. See.

```
for (struct linked_list *p = inputFront; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    enqueue(&outputFront, &outputRear, dequeue(&inputFront, &inputRear));
```

1. You are using a pointer `p` to run through the list, but this pointer is not used inside the loop. The `inputFront` in the statement must be replaced by this pointer `p`. This will allow it to run through every element of the loop.
2. In the `dequeue` function, you are moving the pointer `inputFront` (now `p`). So, if you do `p = p-> next` in the loop, it will be done twice. This has to be removed.

Fixed code is

```
for (struct linked_list *p = inputFront; p != NULL; )
    enqueue(&outputFront, &outputRear, dequeue(&p, &inputRear));

for (struct linked_list *p = outputFront; p != NULL; )
    printf("%s \n", dequeue(&p, &outputRear));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your print loop. You let `p` advance until the end of the list, and you let `dequeue` retrieve the next (first) item in the list. But dequeue *also removes the front* from the list. Following the return, the for-loop now also advances `p`, whose `next` member has jus been advanced already. Given input a b c, I would expect the output now to be a c. If you take a debugger, you can get some more clues.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You're right, the loop was the problem.